# Match html 5 video to css fullscreen background

Tags: css, html, video

I am trying to match an html video to a css fullscreen background that is centered in the screen. I want the video to seamlessly match the background no matter what size the screen is. Please help all you master css guys and gals. Thanks!

the image is at:

[Screenshot of video and background](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oo7wwbjzglukma6/VIDEO-HTML.jpg)

Comment: Can you paste your code please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at the codde in this fantistic site, where the video also is integrated with a map, where you are ind the Video.

http://nrk.no/nordlandsbanen/

Cheers

JanCoyle